# Is it a good idea to backup an Azure VM running MongoDB using Azure Backup?

Tags: mongodb, azure, database-backups

We have a VM that runs a MongoDB and a web api to it.
Currently there is no backup solution enabled.

My goal is to protect data in MongoDB.
Is it a good idea to snapshot the whole Azure VM instance daily?
Or should I go for a database backup solution?